# How to save data on a different table using CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

I have 3 tables named `places`, `images` and `place_images`. I want to save the
IDs of table `images` and `places` to the table `place_images`. I am using
CakePHP as my framework.

I am new to PHP programing and Cake framework.

Here is my code which saves the images:

```
for($img = 0; $img < count($this->request->data['Place']['img']); $img++){
    $file = $this->request->data['Place']['img'];
    if ($file[$img]['tmp_name']) {
        if ($file[$img]['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $new_file = $s3place->upload($file[$img]['tmp_name']);
            $image_data = array(
                'filename' => $new_file,
                'metadata' => '',
                'title' => $this->request->data['Place']['img_title'][$img],
                'description' => $this->request->data['Place']['img_desc'][$img],
                'thumb_ready' => 1
            );
            //pr($image_data). exit;
            if (UserPerm::places_attribute()) {
                $image_data['source_url'] = $this->request->data['Place']['img_source'][$img];
                $image_data['source_name'] = $this->request->data['Place']['img_source_name'][$img];
            }

            App::uses('Image', 'model');
            $Image = new Image();
            $is_new_file = false;
            if (isset($old_data['Image']['id']) && $old_data['Image']['id']) {
                $image_data['id'] = $old_data['Image']['id'];
                $Image->id = $old_data['Image']['id'];
            } else {
                $Image->create();
                $is_new_file = true;
            }

            if ($Image->save($image_data)) {
                if ($is_new_file) {
                    $this->request->data['Place']['image_id'] = $Image->getLastInsertID();
                } else {
                    $this->request->data['Place']['image_id'] = $old_data['Image']['id'];
                }

            // Delete old image in S3
            /*if (isset($old_data['Image']['id']) && $old_data['Image']['id']) {
                  $s3place->del($old_data['Image']['filename']);
              } */
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The image could not be saved. Please, try again.') . $err, 'flash_error');
                return;
            }
     } else {
         $this->Session->setFlash(__('The image could not be uploaded. Please, try again.') . $err, 'flash_error');
         return;
     }
}} // end for loop
```

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in detail in the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html) under [[Associations: Linking Models Together]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) - specifically the part on [[Has and Belongs To Many]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm)

Once your associations are set up correctly, and you're saving per the book's instructions, it will save all the fields automatically.

Comment: thank you for the quick response. I will take a look at your advice.

Comment: Hi Sir, I have followed instruction in [Associations: Linking Models Together] - and I still cant save data to my table. am I missing something?

Comment: Most likely yes. What you described is common and documented.  Try normal testing/fixing - ie get it to work simply, then expand.

Comment: thanks Dave. I managed to make it work by using a recursive. cheers.